# Can custom settings be "passed into" a Contentful UI extension assignment?

Tags: contentful

Is it possible to pass data into UI extensions assignments (meaning UI Extension X assigned to Field Y), in order to alter their functionality slightly for different situations, without having to reimplement the entire extension?

For example, CodeMirror is a really neat embedded editor, but it has a bunch of "modes," depending on what language you're working with.  If we could even pass in a string to represent the desired mode when the extension is assigned to a field, that would remove the need to do a different extension just to use different syntax highlighting.

With this, there could now be a generic "CodeMirror Editor" UI extension which is then just configured a runtime.

On the other end of the extreme, we could specify entire JSON objects when the extension is assigned to a field, to further specify configuration options.

This would make UI extensions so much more...useful.  Does this functionality exist now, or is there some way to reasonably make it work?  Is there some place on the field specification where I can "park" a JSON string, then access it from inside the extension?

Comment: Unfortunately that feature doesn't yet exist :(

Comment: @RouvenWeßling See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wrote something for this, specific to my situation, but generalizable to others. This is an example if a UI extension that retrieves settings from another entry in the space, and uses it to dynamically configure itself.

https://github.com/deanebarker/contentful-code-editor

Comment: Interesting approach, perhaps there should exist some kind of "global settings" object that you could put stuff like this into, instead of "wasting" a content type so to speak.

Comment: There's considerable precedent here. Lots of systems store settings as managed content. Sitecore, for example, stores everything in a "global" tree, even down to buttons in the wysiwyg editor. I just saw the same thing in a a Magnolia demo last week -- settings are just a different branch in the content tree. This is actually so common that I wrote a sidebar about it in my book.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It's not uncommon to create a "settings page" or pull global settings from the start page. It's just always felt a bit off in my opinion. It's not content really. If the CMS could provide some sort of interface for this where you could configure global settings to be arbitrarily consumed by your content, that'd be great. Especially since this is something you do for basically every implementation.

Comment: Perhaps people would like to store them in a different space -- a "settings space," or something. But that brings up access issues.

Answer (score 2):

Contentful has launched something called "**Configuration parameters**" for UI extensions that could be used to solve this issue.

They have two types of parameters, `installation` and `instance` parameters. Installation parameters are set when installing the UI extension, and instance parameters are set when configuring a field on a content type to use the extension. The latter would be perfect for your use case.

To use this feature you need to:

1. Create a parameter definition for the UI extension in the `extension.json` file. E.g. a new instance parameter called "codeMirrorSettings" of type Symbol with name "CodeMirror Settings".
2. Within the extension, fetch the current parameters using `extensionsApi.parameters.instance.codeMirrorSettings`.

Documentation for configuration parameters can be found in Contentful's docs:

- https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/ui-extensions/configuration-parameters
- https://github.com/contentful/ui-extensions-sdk/blob/master/docs/ui-extensions-sdk-frontend.md#extensionparameters

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is just read this setting from another field, be that a string or a json object.

For example the [slug generator](https://github.com/contentful/extensions/tree/master/samples/slug) automatically generates its value from the title field.

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
const cfExt = window.contentfulExtension || window.contentfulWidget


cfExt.init(api => {
    var langField = api.entry.fields.mirrorLang || 'default'
    //Rest of implementation
})
```